# JavaScript onclick function with redirect doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, onclick

I have big trouble now. I am trying to make a small script with plain JavaScript. But I have one problem. If I click on button, nothing happens (but alert works). It seems to be like the page just refresh, because the console log doesn't work too.

```
<form>
    <select class="select" id="test">
        <optgroup>
            <option selected disabled hidden>Default</option>
            <option value="1">Value 1</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
    <button class="btn" onclick="myFunction();">text</button>
</form>



function myFunction() {
    var e = document.getElementById("test"); 
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    if (strUser > 0) {
        window.location.href = 'www.google.com';
    } else {
        alert("Error")
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is console.log? What is 'e'?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. I can think of several reasons why this code doesn't work, but none of the obvious problems in the code you've provided would give the behaviour you describe. At least not without there being other problems too.

Comment: @HereticMonkey — They said they were clicking on a button and didn't mention onchange.

Comment: Updated. HTML added.

Comment: The problem was in <form> tag. Now I feel like a little idiot :^D But thanks to everybody who tried to help. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your button is inside a form. Clicking it will submit the form.

So your onclick function runs, begins navigation to `www.google.com` (a URL which is missing the scheme), and then the form submits and begins navigation to the form's `action` (which is unspecified, so defaults to the URL of the current page).

The second navigation overrides the first, so you load the current page again instead of `www.google.com`.

You need to cancel the default behaviour of the form submission or the submit button.

Using the 1990s approach you are currently using:

```
<button class="btn" onclick="myFunction(); return false">
```

Or using modern code:

```
document.querySelector("form")
    .addEventListener("submit", myFunction);
```

and

```
function myFunction (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // etc
```

Answer (score 1):

getElementbyId just takes the string, it does not include the "#".

Comment: http://jsbin.com/rusisicone/edit?html,js,output — An id is allowed to have a # character in it. We don't know what the OP's HTML looks like, and just having that line return null would not cause the page to refresh as described (at least not in isolation).

Answer (score 0):

@Ondřej Musil, you have to take care when you ask something to don't forget about put details and a more complete code.

I think that I have your answer! But let me know if is that are you trying...
Do you have a Button and a Select? When you perform a click in the button, the will be called that function, right?

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="myFunction()"> Redirect </button>
<select id="test">
  <option value="1"  selected="selected">User 1</option>
  <option value="2">User 2</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
function myFunction() {    
    var e = document.getElementById("test");
        var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    if (strUser > 0) {
        window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
    } else {
        alert("Error")
    }
}
```

Please, try it!

Comment: Thanks for help! The problem was in <form> tag. I had to add this: 'return false;' :) But thanks for help.

Comment: @OndřejMusil, we are here to help! In the next time, remind to put a complete code here, like Quentin said: Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.